# How to view skipped records in pandas read_csv()?

Tags: mysql, pandas, csv

I have a csv file containing some bad or corrupt records. I used the below syntax to skip the bad records when reading the csv file in pandas :

pd.read_csv(csvfile,error_bad_lines=False)

Now how can I view only those records that are skipped when reading the csv file and store them in an external log file ?